# How to force VS2012 to use 32 bit version of Internet Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have a program that launches Internet Explorer from it.  If I open the project in VS2010 and debug it, the browser it uses is Internet Explorer 9 32 bit.  If I open the project in VS2012 and debug it, the browser it uses is Internet Explorer 9 64 bit.

How I can prevent VS2012 from using the 64 bit version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the project to target x86 in the build will force it to use Internet Explorer 32 bit.  If you use Any it will default to the configuration of the computer and in this case x64.